# Reading huge data set from database through java using multi-threading program

Tags: java

In my project I am generating a report. This involves huge data transmission from the DB.

The logic is like user will give certain criteria,based on which first we will fetch parent items from db.There may be 100000 parent items.Not only this after getting this items we are gathering child items of this parent items and there detailed details. All to gather this parent and child information we are putting in one response xml.

It is fine for small records. But for huge records it is taking more time. We are using a tool as a back end system.Which stores the records.It has its own query set so query optimization did not work.All we have to do it with java.

Can any one from the team give some idea how to optimize this.

Comment: What do you plan to improve? Where the bottlenecks exist in your system? If disk system is slow, multi-threading may not improve speed so much. If you use multiple databases, multi-threading concurrent access to databases may improve speed greatly. It all depend structure of your system and characters of parts, databases, network, disks, etc.

Comment: you really need to look at the rate limiting step. Its a bit hard to say from just reading what you have posted. What step is the slowest? The query? The creation of XML? The java processing? The transmission over the network?

Comment: Thanks, I have checked the time it is taking.When we are gathering the parent information .It is not taking much time.But when we are gathering child item details for each parent object it is taking time.

Comment: Do you use a kind of ORM framework or pure SQL with JDBC to communicate with DB? I really hope it is the second one :) Then you could try to build one view to present all information you need to build your XML. Also, check your tables has all required indexes including compound ones which can be used by the query planner subsystem. And finally, you can split that single view by subset of parents (let's say by their birth year) and let a thread to process its own view producing its own part of xml. The final process will merge all parts to the one result file.

Comment: AntolyG  thanks,We are not using any ORM. In backend we are using a product which actually stores all the information. That's why we are unable to do any query optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a true answer, but too long for a comment

You must *benchmark* the different steps:

1. database - time a select extracting all the records (parents + childs) directly on the database (assuming it is a simple database)
2. network - time a transfert of the approximate size of the whole records.
3. processing - store the result on a local file and time the processing reading from local file (you must also time a copy of the file to know the time used to read from disk

Multithreading will only help if the bottleneck is processing.